# ?_method=DELETE is not working in this CRUD app. I am following Colt Steele's Full stack bootcamp

Tags: javascript, crud, destroy

```
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));


app.delete("/comments/:id", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  comments = comments.filter((c) => c.id !== id);
  res.redirect("/comments");
});

<h1>Comment id: <%= comment.id %></h1>
    <h2><%= comment.comment %> - <%=comment.username %></h2>
    <a href="/comments">Back to index</a>
    <a href="/comments/<%= comment.id %>/edit ">Edit Comment</a>
<a href="/comments/<%= comment.id %>/edit ">Edit Comment</a>
    <form method="POST" action="/comments/ <%= comment.id %>?_method=DELETE">
      <button>Delete</button>
    </form>
```

Building a simple CRUD app and the ?_method=DELETE is not working for some reason.  I am able to do everything else, however when I try to delete there is no error.  The page just redirects/refreshes.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing that space here `/comments/ <%= comment.id %>?_method=DELETE"`? Like `/comments/<%= comment.id %>?_method=DELETE"`

Comment: I can't believe that worked lol, thank you so much!